# chart.js version 3 - How to make an overlapping bar chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js3

Is it possible to create a chart like this (following image) using Chart.js version 3?

[image]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stack the x axis together with a smaller bar percentage for the inner bar:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
        barPercentage: 0.6
      },
      {
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 8, 10, 5, 13],
        backgroundColor: 'pink'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.2/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```